# What kind of battery does the Pokémon Go Plus have?

Tags: pokemon-go

I haven't opened my [*Pokémon Go* Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Go#Pok.C3.A9mon_Go_Plus) yet.

What battery does it have inside?

I was thinking of buying a battery later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.digitalspy.com/gaming/pokemon/feature/a808350/your-biggest-pokemon-go-plus-questions-answered/) (specifically, point 13; "Do I need to charge the Pokémon Go Plus?") the battery inside is a **CR2032** lithium coin cell. The Plus's battery life is estimated at 100 hours of use, so if you use it frequently - start stocking up.

Comment: I'm not really seeing a device that actively runs Bluetooth to last 100 hours off a single CR2032.  I'm probably going to give it a more conservative 10 hours of constant use.

Comment: I have a pebble watch with a 130mAh battery, lasts up to a week (160+ hours) at a time, constantly communicating using bluetooth, plus updating a screen, vibrating on notifications etc.  A CR2032 has 225mAh capacity - I see no reason not to believe the 100 hours claim.

Comment: @Nelson It's BLE, and it does absolutely nothing 99.9% of the time. There's no reason why it shouldn't last a hundred hours.

Comment: Yes, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) is a whole different animal from the regular Bluetooth specification. It's barely even Bluetooth at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have had my Go Plus since day one. The battery is indeed a CR2032 coin battery and my experience of using it most of the day, is that your new battery will need replacing every month or so. If you don't use it as much it will last proportionally longer.